# Take average from a map of a map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, average

I have to find average values of a Metric.

Metric class looks like this:

```
public class Metric {

    private String metric_name;

    private double value;

    private long host_id;
}
```

For a single metric, there could be multiple hosts and hence multiple values (per-host).
I want to take average of these per host values and store for each metric.

I thought of making a map of a map like this:

```
Map<String, Map<Long,Double>> metricMap  = new HashMap<String, Map<Long,Double>>();
```

where:

key is a `String` and value is also a `HashMap`, lets call it `valueMap`.

I want to take an average of the values of this `valueMap` and store it into `metricMap` again.

Note, `valueMap` has 100 key value pairs and hence I want their average.

So eventually, I will have only one value per metric giving me its average.

Any pointers or ideas to do this in Java?

I thought of sorting the internal map first and then taking an average. But there are multiple instances of these metrics.

The actual code looks something like this:

```
ArrayList <MetricStore> list = new ArrayList<MetricStore>(); 

    list = importStorage.storage.getList();
    for(MetricStore store: list) {

    //sort and take average of values

    // put it into the HasMap

    }
```

Note: I am importing the data form xml

Problem here is I have multiple Metrics and I cannot store for each one the average values.

Thanks!

Edit:

My source is an XML file looking something like this:

```
        <store>
            <hostid>2</hostid>
            <metric>Bandwidth</metric>
            <value>56.0</value>
        </store>
        <store>
            <hostid>17</hostid>
            <metric>Bandwidth</metric>
            <value>150.841</value>
        </store>
        <store>
            <hostid>86</hostid>
            <metric>Bandwidth</metric>
            <value>30.30</value>
        </store>
```

I am reading it back to my POJO using JAXB.

Comment: Are you going to be using the individual values, or are you only going to use the average afterwards? And what's the `Long` key in the internal map supposed to be?

Comment: @RealSkeptic - I am only interested in the average values. Long is for host_Id as I have multiple hosts in the network and each host has its own value. Eventually, I want to take an average of these host values and store for each metric name.

Comment: Well then, you probably shouldn't have the maps in the Metric at all. Create a static builder method that reads your data and averages it, and creates a Metric with pre-calculated average value.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - While I am reading the data here, I also need to check if it corresponds to which metric. You are right that I need to find average first and then create a metric out of it. But how do I make sure that I am calculating average for a right metric? Is run time type checking a right option to do it and store them probably to take average? But in this case, I need to go on adding condition check for all the mertrics I have.

Comment: It's really hard to answer without knowing the way your source data is organized. Please edit your question and add that information. And you don't compare strings in Java using `==`.

Comment: I have added some more details now.